# How to validate receipt ( In-App purchase)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, asn.1

I have read a lot about apple's receipt validation programming guide and stuck here for several days...

1.asn1c (how to parse)

```
ReceiptModule DEFINITIONS ::=
BEGIN

ReceiptAttribute ::= SEQUENCE {
type    INTEGER,
version INTEGER,
value   OCTET STRING
}

Payload ::= SET OF ReceiptAttribute

END
```

I use this tool to generate some .h/.c files,and I add them to my project:
[image]
I don't know how to use it.

This is in-app purchase receipt format.

```
InAppAttribute ::= SEQUENCE {
   type                   INTEGER,
   version                INTEGER,
   value                  OCTET STRING
}

InAppReceipt ::= SET OF InAppAttribute
```

I can't use `asn1c -fnative-types filename` to generate any file.I got this error :

```
ASN.1 grammar parse error near line 1 (token "::="): parse error, unexpected TOK_PPEQ, expecting TOK_DEFINITIONS
Cannot parse "IAP.asn1"
```

If this success , how to use it? Just add to my project?

2.OpenSSL? Do I have to use it? `libcrypto.a, libel.a`How to use these files? Do I have to re-generate? (EL Capitan vs Xcode 7.0.1)

3.AppleIncRootCertificate.cer , Is this file necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer you question number 1.

It looks like you are trying to use the ASN.1 type definitions without placing them inside of an ASN.1 module.  All ASN.1 definitions need the following before and after them:

ModuleName DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

... your type and value definitions ...

END

Please add these before and after your definitions (replacing ModuleName with a name of your choice that begins with an uppercase letter) and see if the error message goes away.